# Change value in console

Tags: javascript

I try to change value "toFixed" in console with help "if&else".
But console giving me old value.
     for example :

```
 if ((s - s.toFixed(2)) != 0);{
    s = s.toFixed(2);
    }
    else { s = s.toFixed(0);}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the semicolon, because this is an emoty statement and the rest throws an error with the `else` statement.

```
if (s - s.toFixed(2) != 0) {
//                        ^ remove semicolon here
  s = s.toFixed(2);
} else {
  s = s.toFixed(0);
}
```